# How can I support ancient browsers on my webserver?

Tags: http, internet-explorer-6, lighttpd, java-6

I would like to use HTTPS on my website, but I also need to support ancient browsers such as IE <11 (especially Windows XP) and Java 6.

This basically means I should only send HTTPS redirects to new browsers or browsers I can't be sure are these old browsers.

What should I put on my lighttpd config to achieve these results?

Comment: Read the documentation and create your redirect if $HTTP["scheme"] == "http" inside a condition based on User-Agent (using $REQUEST_HEADER["User-Agent"])  Documentation: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_Configuration

Comment: Why do you think old browsers have problems with HTTPS?

Comment: @JulianReschke I don't think those old browsers can handle ECDHE and stuff

Comment: Ah, so it's not about HTTPS, but about the TLS version and supported algorithms. You may want to clarify that in the question.

Comment: @JulianReschke I don't think there's any way to provide high security to new browsers and low security to old browsers without affecting the security of new browsers.